# Source control solutions for the traveling man

Tags: version-control, versioning, desktop-application

I'm travelling alot and I have personal projects that I need to work on during this time.  Sometimes when waiting for the train at the terminal, at home, and at work.  I need to keep the source versioned somehow.  I don't mind installing an application on each desktop.  I need a way to sync between them, maybe with Dropbox?  What options do I have?

please not git hub, and not payed solution , something private. and simple

Comment: when you say "something private" are you open to hosted services with private repos or are you looking for something which you would host yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at using a hosted version control solution like [Github](http://github.com) or [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org).  You have to pay for private repos on Github, but private repos on Bitbucket are free.

Comment: @user63898 - you have local repo with full history anyway, you *can* push to BB, but *not must* do it on every commit - it's DVCS after all

Comment: @user63898 - I suggest you take a look at the "distributed version control system" link that Martin posted in his answer.  DVCS' allow you to have the power to version your code (commit changes) while you are offline and then push to another repo when you are back online.  You would then sync your machines through this online repo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [distributed version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) such as [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). This allows you to

- make off-line commits: you can make commits in the train, at home, or at work
- synchronize the repositories with each other
- host your code on sites like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (Mercurial and Git hosting, free private repositories) or [GitHub](https://github.com/) (Git hosting, paid private repositories).

Comment: Do we have (good!!!) portable Git or Mercurial client? OP stated - "I don't mind installing an application on each desktop"

Comment: Well, what about `hg`? :-) I just wanted to point him to DVCS since that let's him work offline and at the same time sync repositories in a robust way. Choosing a good client is another question.

Comment: really, **what** about hg? Can I (in Win-world) just copy <somedir> and have **working Mercurial**? Why, in this case, I see only Mercurial 2.0.2 Inno Setup installer|Mercurial 2.0.2 MSI installer|Mercurial 2.0.2 Python 2.6 package? A rhetorical question...

Comment: @LazyBadger: ehm, what are you talking about? He wrote that he don't mind installing a program on each machine and I suggest installing Mercurial (or Git). But if you want a portable version, then you can use the [portable TortoiseHg](http://portableapps.com/node/28151).

Comment: *installing hg* means **installing anyway**. OK, portable TortoiseHg is answer

Answer (score 1):

As already was mentioned - use DVCS of choice. If you don't want hosted solution (while private Bitbucket is good), you can

- copy repository *as is* (Git, Mercurial...) from one workplace to another and back
- use portable clients without installing (PortableGit, Syntevo Smart* portable versions)

or

- [Fossil SCM](http://www.fossil-scm.org/) is cross-plarform, single-exe small DVCS, which store repository in one file. Easy, fast, extremely mobile

Comment: im looking for something like this (Fossil ) with more GUI client , not command line

Comment: @user63898 - portable TortoiseHg?!

Comment: is there such thing ? portable , also i never used it before

Answer (score 0):

Try [github](https://github.com/). Its a great version control program that is free so long as you don't mind your files being public. If you need privacy you can pay for private repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you mentioned "source" above, but there is a rather famous article written by Joey Hess titled [Keeping Your Life in Subversion](http://kitenet.net/~joey/svnhome/). Apparently, he's still doing it even though the article is from 2005 (although he's moved to git).

There's even a [mailing list](https://lists.madduck.net/mailman/listinfo/vcs-home) for people who keep their homes in version control repositories!